# using regex to break code into scopes - java

Tags: java, regex, string, compilation

as a HW assignment i have to create a simple program to verify that some simplifeid java code is valid.
i want to use regex (assuming this is the right tool) to break code pieces into different scopes.

basically,given a string, i want all parts of it of the form:

*some chars*(){
*some chars*
}

for example, for this code:

```
void foo() {
char a = 'a';
if(3=2){
  double d;
 }
return;
}
```

i would like to get a 2 cells array of this structure:
    cell 0: void foo() {char a = 'a';if(3=2){double d;}return;}
    cell 1: if(3=2){double d;}

what is the way to do it in java?
i tried this without success:

```
Pattern blocks = Pattern.compile("[[^\\n].*\\{.*\\}]*");
String[] sepblock = (str+str+str).split("[^\\n].*\\{.*\\}");
Matcher match = blocks.matcher(str+str+str);
while (match.find()) {          System.out.println((str+str+str).substring(match.start(),match.end()));
    }
```

the output was:

```
void foo() {

char a = 'a';

return;

}


void foo() {

char a = 'a';

return;

}


void foo() {

char a = 'a';

return;

}
```

the wanted output is a 3 cell array, where each cell contains a String which is one of the foo's.

Comment: I doubt regular expressions are the right tool for this task. Perhaps you should try to take a look at antlr, a parser generator with a pretty straight forward syntax.

Comment: i cant use antlr. will i have to do this "by hand"?

Comment: The same thought here: regular expressions is not the right tool. Also, define, please, what is "simplified java code". To what extent it is simplified? As you can't use any side parser implementations, then do it yourself: it is an interesting task, by the way.

Comment: `brake` (to slow down) is spelled `break` (to separate).

Comment: its very simplified. the specifications are long, but the code is mostly variable/function declerations, if conditions and while loops.

other then regex i think a stack would be good too, but i hoped for smthing simpler.

Comment: You can't use regular expressions for this, because Java is not a regular language. You'll have to parse it, which could be quite complex depending on the subset you're working with, given you can't use a parser generator.